# How to display a DFP ad in a slideshow?

Tags: google-dfp

I want to display a DFP ad in a slideshow built with the Fotorama plugin.

It works fine but the ad disappears in fullscreen or if I am sliding to other frames and back to the ad-frame.  The iframe-document-body becomes empty of the ad-unit.

I can solve it with `googletag.pubads().refresh([specificSlot]);`
But I don't want a new refresh/new ad, I want the same ad to be shown again with no extra counting.

Can I simply use `googletag.display('id-of-ad-unit-div');`?

Comment: You may have to modify the way the slideshow works.   It sounds like it may remove nodes from the DOM and then put them back later.   You might have to use a slideshow that moves them off-screen so that it doesn't effect their contents.